# Increase Node memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, protractor, v8

I'm running Protractor (which uses Node, which uses V8) in order to do run some browser tests. I've started getting the following out of memory errors:

```
02:34:40.051 FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
02:34:40.051 
02:34:40.051 <--- Last few GCs --->
02:34:40.051 
02:34:40.052  1003893 ms: Scavenge 1397.2 (1458.3) -> 1397.2 (1458.3) MB, 1.1 / 0 ms (+ 59.3 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
02:34:40.052  1004839 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.2 (1458.3) -> 1397.2 (1458.3) MB, 945.8 / 0 ms (+ 118.0 ms in 11 steps since start of marking, biggest step 59.3 ms) [last resort gc].
02:34:40.052  1005782 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.2 (1458.3) -> 1397.2 (1458.3) MB, 943.3 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
02:34:40.052 
02:34:40.052 
02:34:40.052 <--- JS stacktrace --->
02:34:40.052 
02:34:40.052 ==== JS stack trace =========================================
02:34:40.052 
02:34:40.052 Security context: 0x1e4bb62e3ac1 <JS Object>
02:34:40.052     2: encode64s [/var/lib/tests/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/formatter/json_formatter.js:~126] [pc=0x2c20b5f516fc] (this=0x1e4bb62fc3c9 <JS Global Object>,input=0x39ae3bb04101 <Very long string[150450]>)
02:34:40.052     3: embedding [/var/lib/tests/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/formatter/json_formatter.js:...
02:34:40.052
```

From what I can gather, this is likely related to Node having a default of 512mb of memory allocated and essentially running out.

Now, I know that I can increase the amount of RAM allocated to Node with the "max_old_space_size" argument, however, the Protractor "wrapper" script starts up Node with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test';

require('../lib/cli.js');
```

and adding this option to the top line, after "node" doesn't work (running protractor just hangs and doesn't produce any output).

How can I increase the amount of RAM that is allocated to Node (and V8) in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Protractor, but instead of executing the file directly, use node to execute it.  `node --max_old_space_size=2048 protractor.js`, or something like that.  Also, are you sure you're not simply running out of memory on the box?  Node by default will use a lot more than 512MB.  There are some limits, but they're not as straightforward as a cap on memory for the whole process.  The limitations have more to do with memory allocations on the JS side, which is not all of your application.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, eager to know how to resolve it